# How well does the Android Phone Emulator reflect the performance?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I've been playing around with `OpenGL ES` development on Android. `OpenGL ES` applications seem to run slowly in the Emulator on my development machine. Does this reflect likely performance of actual hardware? I'm concerned about spending too much time developing an application if the graphics performance is going to be sluggish.

Comment: Have a look at this it answers your question!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893273/how-does-android-emulator-performance-compare-to-real-device-performance

Comment: The Emulators are getting better every day, now (2017) there are a lot of them, bluestack, GenyMotion, Andy,... to name a few

Answer (score 9):

The emulator is super slow on my `Mobile Intel Pentium M 725, 1600 MHz`.

I'm assuming the emulator isn't representative of real world performance.

Answer (score 1):

Emulator is soo slow ,that in some cases an openGL application wouldn't even start when using it.
While the actual hardware of android can even be so strong,that you can even play GTA on it.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring VM Acceleration on Windows

Virtual machine acceleration for Windows requires the installation of the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel HAXM). The software requires an Intel CPU with Virtualization Technology (VT) support and one of the following operating systems:

Windows 7 (32/64-bit)
Windows Vista (32/64-bit)
Windows XP (32-bit only)
To install the virtualization driver:

Start the Android SDK Manager, select Extras and then select Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager.
After the download completes, execute 
`<sdk>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.exe`

Follow the on-screen instructions to complete installation.
After installation completes, confirm that the virtualization driver is operating correctly by opening a command prompt window and running the following command:

```
sc query intelhaxm
```

You should see a status message including the following information:
SERVICE_NAME: `intelhaxm`

```
   ...
   STATE              : 4  RUNNING

   ...
```

To run an x86-based emulator with VM acceleration:

If you are running the emulator from the command line, just specify an x86-based AVD:

```
emulator -avd <avd_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

After the new update the emulators have become much more reliable but still can't be taken as the way to check the performance of your application. Till now testing the application of real devices are more reliable then emulators.

Answer (score 0):

With the new emulator of Android Studio 2.0, if you have good computer it runs quite smoothly, at leat for my application!

Check the [features](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/devices/emulator.html)!