# Why is my app running slow on an older version of android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am building an app for college project, when I tested it on Virtual Device- Pixel 2 API 30 Android 11, it is running smoothly, but when I am testing it on my physical device which is Redmi Note 3 running on Android 6 (Marshmallow) it is sticking.

Comment: if you can't use a specific title, adding in underscores to bypass the system doesn't really make it a better title. just try to put your title into a question format and explain what you're struggling with, chances are it'll be a better title than_writing_it_like_this :)

Comment: this might be the answer to a question that is almost like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662117/performance-of-app-on-android-phone-emulator-vs-actual-device

Answer (score 0):

Reason is android version. Try creating a virutal system which has android 6 marshmallow, it will behave same.

Comment: Then what could be the solution, if I want to run my device of low end.

Comment: Optimize your app. And why you are trying to make it compatible with version 6. Even version 12 is released this year. You can still get million of downloads. If you keep version above 9.